# JQuery datepicker: Disable dates explicitly enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker that filters selectable dates. The requirements are only T, W, Th and one random Saturday a month. I have been able to accomplish this so far using the code below. Now my customer wants to be able to block out certain days on T, W, Th for various reasons (e.g. Holiday, Office closing, etc.). I am not sure how to accomplish this new request. Any ideas?

```
var SaturdayDate = ["7-25-2020", "8-15-2020" ];

$(function() {

  $("#my_date_picker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      return [dt.getDay() == 2 || dt.getDay() == 3 || dt.getDay() == 4 || enableThisDay(dt), ""];
    },
    minDate: 1
  });
});
            
function enableThisDay(date) {
  var oDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('m-d-yy', date);
  if ($.inArray(oDate, SaturdayDate) != -1) {
    return [true];
  }
}
```

Comment: The date format in `var oDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('m-d-yy', date);` doesnt seem to match the format in `SaturdayDate` variable. Have you checked that? The format hould be `m-dd-yyyy`

Comment: The Saturday function works properly. I need to disable specific dates on T, W, Th which all those days have been explicitly enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datepicker accepts an array of dates that need to be disabled.

You should be able to disable dates in the following way:

```
var dates = ["20/07/2020", "21/07/2020", "22/07/2020", "23/07/2020"];

function disableDates(date) {
  var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);

  let isDefaultDisabled = false;
  if(date.getDay()===2 || date.getDay()==3 || date.getDay()==4){
    isDefaultDisabled = true;
  }

  return [ isDefaultDisabled && dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
}


$(function() {
     $("#date").datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: disableDates
     });
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/idhruvs/wdkprbsL/9/

Comment: Thanks Dhruv. I have seen this approach and it works on its own but when added to the other params beforeShaowDay, it has no affect. So, for example if I add the DisableDates function as below, it does not work. beforeShowDay:function(dt) { return [dt.getDay()==2 || dt.getDay()==3 || dt.getDay()==4||enableThisDay(dt) || DisableDates(dt), "" ];}, minDate:0

Comment: I think it would be advisable to move the whole logic for checking if date needs to be disabled or not should be moved to the disbaleDates function. THis gives us more control over our logic. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You may refer to the fiddle included in my answer. The dates `21/7/2020`, `22/7/2020`, and `23/7/2020` correspond to `T, W, TH`, but since they are mentioned into the `dates` array, they are disabled.

Comment: The JSFiddle link in my answer is updated according to my answer. It should work fine

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you, thank you, thank you Dhruv!

Answer (score 3):

I would keep any array to use `Date` objects rather than strings, eliminating formatting as a potential issue. I'd have two arrays: the "random" Saturdays and the holidays. Then I'd have a single function that checks if a date is enabled or not.

```js
// Dates in JS use 0 indexed months, so 6 is July and 7 is August
var saturdays = [ new Date(2020, 6, 25), new Date(2020, 7, 15) ];
var holidays = [ new Date(2020, 6, 22), new Date(2020, 6, 2), new Date(2020, 7, 13) ];

$(function() {
  $("#my_date_picker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: enableThisDay,
    minDate: 1
  });
});

function enableThisDay(date) {
  var enabled = false;
  // if it's Tue, Wed, Thu, enable it
  if ([2,3,4].includes(date.getDay())) {
    enabled = true;
  }
  // if it's a holiday, disable it
  if (holidays.some(h => h.valueOf() === date.valueOf())) {
    enabled = false;
  }
  // if it's a saturday, disable it
  // note that if it's a saturday, that overrides holiday
  // if holidays override saturday, swap this statement with 
  // the one immediately above
  if (saturdays.some(s => s.valueOf() === date.valueOf())) {
    enabled = true;
  }
  return [enabled, ""];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylehseet">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylehseet">
<input type="text" id="my_date_picker">
```